# Slick projection operator/method documentation in scaladocs

Tags: scala, slick

I extracted the following snippet from a Slick table definition:

```
object Person extends Table[(String, String, Int)]("person"){
  ...
  def firstName = column[Long]("firstName")
  ...
  def * = firstName ~ lastName ~ age
}
```

My question is: **where is the ~ projection operator/method defined in the Slick scaladocs?** Can anyone please point me to the relevant link in the scaladoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [Column](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.Column). There's

```
 final def ~[U](b: Column[U]): Projection2[T, U]
```

Comment: Use the reference docs: these letters below the top left search bar: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/#index.index-_ and control+f.